# MongoDB - basic data design

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a list of Google map markers that I'm associating images with. Each marker can have multiple images\video's and each image can be thumbnailed to multiple sizes.

- eg. I have markerID  555
- I'm storing the images in GridFS and add MarkerID and Thumbnail Size as MetaData properties.

To get a list of images for a given marker I simply search the fs.files collection as follows.

```
{"metadata.size": imageSize, "metadata.markerID": markerID }
```

Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: "list of markers for a given marker"? This question is a bit vague to me. Not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, edited the question. It should have read To get a list of images for a given marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have index on the search criteria and enough RAM to hold all the index in memory, you should be ok with that. 
Please note that in your example above, you need a compound index, see [Mongo Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/) for more information about mongo indexes.